# tag helpers is wrong route link using net core 3.1 LTS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use ASP.NET Core 3.1 LTS and route setting like this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Backend",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

                 endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

and my areas razor page have a tag helper

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-area="Backend" asp-controller="Article" asp-action="Create"> Create</a>
```

usually this link will be `/backend/article/create`

but result is `/article/create?area=backend`

why result is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The registering order of routes matters.

   ```
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
       // register this route before the default one
       endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "Backend",
           pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
       endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "default",
           pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
   });
   ```
2. Make sure the `area` of `Backend` exists. Otherwise, it will be treated as querystring. For example, if you have already had an `Area` of `Backend`(Need to use the standard **Area Folder Structure + Namespace**, and annotate the controller with **`[Area("Backend")]`**, see [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1#areas-for-controllers-with-views))

   ```cs
   [Area("Backend")]      // important
   public class ArticleController : Controller  
   {
       public IActionResult Create(){ ...}
   ```

   then the following code

   ```
   <a asp-area="Backend" asp-controller="Article" asp-action="Create"> Create</a>
   <a asp-area="AnAreaThatDoesnotExist" asp-controller="Article" asp-action="Create"> Create</a>
   ```

   will generate routes as below:

   ```
   <a href="/Backend/Article/Create"> Create</a>
   <a href="/Article/Create?area=AnAreaThatDoesnotExist"> Create</a>
   ```

   Note we specify an parameter of `area=AnAreaThatDoesnotExist` which doesn't exist at all and then the `area=AnAreaThatDoesnotExist` will be used as query string.